# How to implement Google Fonts in ggplot2 graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

Is there a way to directly access and implement free fonts (like Google Fonts) with R for graphs (`ggplot2`), without having them installed on my PC or Mac?

Comment: Have a look at https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if I were you, I'd use this `showtext` package that seems to have a function that looks like this :

```
library(showtext)
font_add_google(name = "Amatic SC", family = "amatic-sc")
```

I bet this could solve your problem

You can maybe find more documentation on the package page directly (update --> link in the comment of your question, thanks Stefan) but I found all of this on this page

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/03/adding-custom-fonts-to-ggplot-in-r/

Answer (score 2):

The solution has changed a bit in these years. `font_add_google()` was moved to the `sysfonts` package. You also need to activate `showtext`.

To the beginning of your script or your Quarto file add:

```r
sysfonts::font_add_google(name = "Amatic SC", family = "amatic-sc")
showtext::showtext_auto()
```