# ggplot Custom fonts not working in Quarto

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, quarto

When I render a ggplot with custom fonts it works in the IDE however in Quarto and RMarkdown I keep getting this error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
Calls: .main ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
```

The fonts are all installed on my system, but not recognized by Quarto or RMakrdown.
For example, here is my script:

````
---
title: "TEST"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

This plot works:
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  count (cyl) |>  
  ggplot (aes (x = cyl, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs (title = "Plot 1") + 
  geom_text (aes (label = n), 
             vjust = -1)
```

This plot does not:

 ```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
mtcars |>
  count (cyl) |>  
  ggplot (aes (x = cyl, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs (title = "Plot 2") + 
  geom_text (aes (label = n), 
             vjust = -1,
             family = "Montserrat") + 
  theme (text = element_text(size = 12,  family = "Montserrat"))
```
````

Comment: Normally you need another library like `showtext` or `extrafont` to display custom fonts. Did you maybe run that code in your IDE but not in your Rmarkdown document?

Comment: It sources a script that calls in the fonts.

Comment: I don't see the `source()` in the example you provided so the problem isn't exactly reproducible. Maybe for the example just include that code in the markdown file itself.

Comment: The example shows the issue that I have. The fonts are loaded on my system but not recognized when the document is rendered. That's my issue.

Comment: I believe Montserrat is a google font. See here for the code to use google font in your ggplot code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302413/implement-google-fonts-in-ggplot2-graphs. that code needs to be run in each R session where you want to use the font so it needs to be in your markdown code as well.

Answer (score 4):

Missed a step. I added

```
extrafont::loadfonts(quiet = TRUE)
```

At the beginning of the script and it works now.